# What's the distribution of $L_1$ norm of Gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, normed-spaces

Suppose we have a Multivariate Gaussian random variable $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$. What's the distribution of $\|X\|_1$?

My thinking:
There are a lot of articles talking about the distribution of $\|X\|_2$, But how about $L_1$ norm?

[Finding distribution of distance from origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238204/finding-distribution-of-distance-from-origin)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-random-points-in

Comment: @jorikiit does not sum directly. We have an abs for each component.