# What is the distribution of the sum of the absolute value of i.i.d. 1D Gaussian variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

In my case, each sum contains 264 summands, so results that only hold in the limit of infinitely-many summands may also be useful if the finite case can't be conveniently described.

This is a special case of [What's the distribution of $L_1$ norm of Gaussian random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829074/whats-the-distribution-of-l-1-norm-of-gaussian-random-variables) (which does not have an answer).

Comment: Each summand is $\chi_1$-distributed; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) if you can't work out the mean & variance. The sum of many of these is approximately Normal.